# Detect if int changes per 100

Tags: ios, objective-c

Pretty much summed up my question in the title. If I have a int and it reaches the 100 milestone followed by 200 and onwards. How would I detect this without needing to write multiple if statements?

Comment: "Modulo arithmetic" is something that every programmer should be at least moderately familiar with.

Comment: Look into KVO. It's probably what you want if I've correctly interpreted what you mean by "detect". You should really elaborate more in your question if you want relevant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulo operator to detect when the number, divided by 100, leaves no remainder and is therefore a multiple of 100:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    if ((i % 100) == 0) {
        // Do thing every 100
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3629527 Nope, you can go to `INT_MAX` without issue (answer edited to increase example limit).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(myInt % 100 == 0)
{
  // Do Something
}
```

This will be true if your number is divisible by 100, which is what you're interested in.